# STI and extending Subclasses to include 'extra' columns in a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, sti

Maybe STI isn't what I want, and I'm open to all suggestions, but for the sake of this questions let's assume the following real world situation:

You want your app to house API data for different Mail Vendors.  Using STI, you have the following models

```
class MailSetting < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

end


class MailChimp < MailSetting

end

class AWeber < MailSetting

end

class PostageApp < MailSetting

end
```

Now let's pull up some console action:

```
user = User.first
setting = user.create_mail_setting(:type => "MailChimp")
```

Ok, now you want to add the API key settings.  MailChimp just uses an api_key.  Aweber may user an api_key and signature, and Postageapp, say, uses an api_key and token system.

Would you extend each subclass to include whatever columns you needed in the database?
Would you scrap STI all together and just make regular classes say, `MailChimp`, that inherits from AR?

My reasoning for STI was that i know all of my users will have a MailSetting, it's the type that may expand over time.  However, i find it a pain in the butt to extend these subclasses this way cause you can't do things like `user.mail_setting.connect` without knowing what subclass they are from, and then, what i needed to connect these guys?

Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use Polymorphic classes instead of STI

**UPD**

some links:

- http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails
- http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/howtos/db-relationships/polymorphic

**UPD 2**

Imagine, we need Post model. And we have Article and Topic that inherit from Post.

```
rails g model Post title:string body:text content_type:string content_id:integer
```

So `title` and `body` are common fields for Topic and Article. Lets now create other models with `user_id` field in Topic and `link` in Article

```
rails g model Topic user_id:integer
rails g model Article link:string
```

Now we will edit models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :content, :polymorphic => true, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :post, :as => :content, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :post, :as => :content, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

It can be quite complicated, but digg this way :)

Comment: yeah true. probably should investigate what this would look like in terms of my app.  Thanks.  I'll come back and accept if it works.

Comment: When you are using polymorph classes each class has got its own table and parent's, so it is that what you want. I've just added some interesting links.

Comment: The thing is with polymorphic you REUSE one model and all it's db columns over many classes, vs, what i'm doing here (or thinking of) is having a parent class with a set of 'common' columns, and then wanting to extend and use new columns, based on the subclass that is referred to in 'type'.

Comment: No, you don't understand. You `REUSE one model and all it's db columns over many classes` in either STI and Polymorphic. But while you are using Polymorphic classes they can have their own dbtables. While STI class is tableless class. I'll try now add exampple to my comment.

Comment: In Polymorpic you reuse only its table columns, and with STI you reuse either model methods and table columns :)

Answer (score 3):

You may consider using the `store_accessor` method from [`ActiveRecord::Store`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html).

The STI store approach [given here](http://velocitylabs.io/blog/2015/04/20/sti-store/) demonstrates how you can give individual sub-classes different accessors, which are serialized in to a single column on the super-class.

If you're using PostgreSQL >= 9.2 then this works perfectly with its JSON type, if not then you can let Rails do the serializing (by using `store` instead of `store_accessor`.

TLDR (assuming PostgreSQL >= 9.2):

Add a migration:

```
add_column :mail_settings, :vendor_settings, :json
```

Define relevant attributes in sub-classes:

```
class MailChimp < MailSetting
    store_accessor :vendor_settings, :api_key
    validates :api_key, presence: true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like your schema is sufficiently formless that you'd be better off using a schema-free database. One of the "NoSQL" document based solutions, perhaps? That way you can add and remove fields to your records as you please.

Comment: Last year I tried those, but rails enforces a schema of some sort, even though NoSQL can support any column... it's Rails that expects the schema.  If not, you have to rewrite everything, factories/fixtures, how that is loaded into your app.  I started down that path last year, but maybe it's changed.  It sure was a PITA then however.